# How to fix "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: socket" and "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm writing a simple flask application in python using flask-socket. On the console I'm facing:

> "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: socket"

and

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

I'm attaching snippets of codes that might be relevant. I'd appreciate any hints.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //connect to websocket
    var io = require('/Users/august/Desktop/project2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio');

    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    //when connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        // button should emit 'send message' event
        document.querySelector("#submit-message").onclick = () => {
            const message = document.querySelector("#message").value;
            socket.emit('send message', {"message": message});
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show dependencies list: `pip freeze` or content of `requirements.txt`.
And I not sure that `var io = require('/Users/august/Desktop/project2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio');` is good idea, because it is directory.

Comment: Sure. Pip freeze gives me the following result: astroid==2.2.5
Click==7.0
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.7.7
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Session==0.3.1
Flask-SocketIO==4.1.0
isort==4.3.17
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pbr==5.2.1
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
python-engineio==3.8.1
python-socketio==4.1.0
six==1.12.0
stevedore==1.30.1
typed-ast==1.3.1
virtualenv==16.6.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
Werkzeug==0.15.4
wrapt==1.11.1

Comment: Requirements.txt for this excercise: Flask
Flask-SocketIO
I'm sorry for the weird looking previous message, that's my first questions here.

Comment: Ah, and I used var io = require('/Users/august/Desktop/project2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio'); trying to solve the previous error "can't find variable: io". I don't know what are the correct approaches, I just hoped it would work.

Comment: For including socket.io.js try using of `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`. See [https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization). But I recommend you get socket.io.js with bower or npm, or download it to static directory of flask app. And remove `var io = require('/Users/august/Desktop/project2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio');`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I should've read flask-socketio documentaion before! Thanks a lot, you solved my problem:)

Comment: I am happy i helped.